# What's about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\pi_2(n)}{n^2}$, on assumption of the Twin Prime Conjecture?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, prime-numbers, asymptotics, mobius-function

I believe that's is possible on assumption of the [Twin Prime Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime), that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\pi_2(n)}{n^2}$$
converges following the guideline of the answer (see the reference).

One has that there exists a integer $n_0$ such that being $\pi_2(x)$ the twin prime-counting function $$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\biggl(\frac{\pi_2(n)}{n} - \frac{1}{\log^2 n}\biggr),$$ converges absolutely because on our assumption $$\frac{\pi_2(n)}{n} - \frac{1}{\log^2 n} \in O\bigl((\log n)^{-3}\bigr),$$ since if the Twin Prime conjecture is true then $\pi_2(n)=O\left(\frac{n}{\log ^2 n}\right)$.

And now, one has that since the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{\log ^2 n}\right)_{n\geq n_0}$ converges to $0$ and is monotonically decreasing, so by [Dirchlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) $$\sum_{n = n_0}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n\log ^2 n}$$ converges (conditionally). It follows that $$\sum_{n = n_0}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)\pi_2(n)}{n^2}$$
converges (conditionally), as it is the sum of two convergent series.

> **Question.** On assumption of the Twin Prime Conjecture was right my calculations? Can you improve or provide us some details of some step, especially doing focus about convergence issues (with our assumption)? **Many thanks.**

---

**Reference:**

This was from an answer of my previous post [What's about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\pi(n)}{n^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048317/whats-about-the-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mun-pinn2)

Comment: You don't even need the conjecture. We know that $\pi_2(n) \leqslant \frac{Cn}{(\log n)^2}$ for some $C > 0$ unconditionally, and so $$\biggl\lvert\frac{\mu(n)\pi_2(n)}{n^2}\biggr\rvert < \frac{C}{n(\log n)^2}$$ shows absolute convergence of the series.

Comment: Ups! Since there was in the literature the asymptotic equivalence that is the statement of the Twin Prime Conjecture, I tried translate in big oh notation, and copy/paste your answer. But I don't know these your news statemets. Many thans @DanielFischer

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I read in Wikipedia that is the *modern version of Brun's argument*. Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: $\sum_n \frac{1}{n \log^2(n)}$ converges because $\sum_k 2^k \frac{1}{2^k \log^2(2^k)}$ converges https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: Many thanks @user1952009